# Regex - Replace tags and special characters, saving the text within the tags

Tags: python, regex

I have a file that has things such as:

```
SomeText `SomeOtherText`
```

and

```
SomeOtherTextAgain:
* Text1
```

I'm trying to substitute the `` ` and * `` characters such that my output is:

```
SomeText \\text{ SomeOtherText }
```

and

```
SomeOtherTextAgain:
\\begin{itemize}
\item Text1
\\end{itemize}
```

So something like:

- `* mystring \n` becomes `\\begin{itemize} \n \item mystring \n \\end{itemize}`
- `mystring` becomes `\\texttt{mystring }`

I tried doing this with the substitute option from the regular expression library provided by python, but I don't know how to save the text in between my replacements. For example, the star I replace using the following:

```
re.sub('\*.*','\\\\begin{itemize} \n \\item \n \\\\end{itemize}',mystring)
```

However, I lose the text captured by the `.*`. 
Is what I'm trying to do possible with regular expressions or should I figure out a different solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is possible with regex, you place text you want to preserve into parentheses and then refer to it in repl string by "\1" (for first one, \2 for second etc.):

```
import re
mystring = '* Text1'
print re.sub(r'\* (.*)',r'\\begin{itemize} \n\\item \1 \n\\end{itemize}',mystring)
```

Output:

```
\begin{itemize} 
\item Text1 
\end{itemize}
```

For more details see http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for!